# BigInteger imlementation requirement for SHA-256

Tags: sha-256

Which BigInteger is needed for implementing SHA-256?
SHA-256 has 64 hex symbols as output. I could use the data structure "string" to calculate the SHA-256 or a BigInteger.

Do I need `uint256_t` in the programming language C++ because I have 256 bits (0 and 1) and so the numbers from 0 to $2^{256} - 1$?

I first implemented SHA-256 with strings as variables and implemented functions for addition of two strings and so on. But maybe it is faster to implement SHA-256 with BigIntegers?

Answer (score 7):

SHA-256 operates on 32-bit integers, with each 32-bit integer mapping to 4 bytes (big-endian). The 64-byte input block is turned into 16 32-bit integers (`uint32_t[16]`), the 32-byte state/output represents 8 32-bit integers (`uint32_t[8]`). At no point does SHA-256 use big integers.

SHA-512 is similar, but uses 64-bit integers instead.